# shell script text processing

Tags: shell, text

I am working on a **shell script** to capture all instances names (only) in an az. I am using aws-cli to **fetch the list**. When i fire the command via script i get the list which is long, i have shortened for it as this is just example. I receive below response to my query.

```
[ [ "host_abc" ], [ "host_xyz" ], [ "host_foo" ], [ "host_bar" ] ]
```

I just want **capture the host names only** and **get rid of all other special characters** like those square brackets, commas and double quotes. I want to get output as copied below.

```
host_abc
host_xyz
host_foo
host_bar
```

Is there a way to filter such response stored in variable or a file in a shell script? Thank you

Comment: Q: Is there a way to filter such response stored in variable or a file in a shell script?  A: If you're in a Linux shell, then your best bet is to learn a little [sed](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed): https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/the-basics-of-using-the-sed-stream-editor-to-manipulate-text-in-linux.  Otherwise, for other shells (including Windows PowerShell), learn some basic regex: https://www.javatpoint.com/regex

Comment: if your data is in json format, it is best to use a json library, rather then trying to treat it as ascii strings and slice it up with sed/aqk.  it will serve you well.   unfortunetly, unix shell does not have built in json scripting, but there is a tool call jq.  also, it is easy to create a small python script to properly read that data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your system has [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), it is really helpful for things like this:

```
aws-cli <whatever> | jq -r 'flatten | join("\n")'
```